I want to upgrade my turbo in my chevy cruze
I'm new to modifying cars just got a chevy cruze and was wondering if I can upgrade my turbocharger on it it's a stock 1.4-liter turbocharged I-4 2010 chevy cruze eco

Would you please add another paragraph by clicking the EDIT below your question? In the new paragraph, please say what you don't like about the way the car performs with stock equipment and what you hope to accomplish by upgrading the turbo. And did you have any other mods in mind? Or are you limiting this to just a turbo upgrade and nothing else?

Also, what are your goals? What are you trying to accomplish? Anything is possible given time, money, and knowledge.

As others have mentioned in the comments the best way to go about this is to start with a goal and then look at what you need to change/upgrade to achieve that goal.
From "upgrade my turbocharger" I think it's a safe bet you're looking for better acceleration and top speed and in order to do that you want more power and torque.
Depending on the gains you're looking for answer might be a relatively simple (and cost effective!) re-map - a quality tuner should be able to achieve an extra 20-30bhp and 40lbft out of the stock engine and turbocharger on that car which is quite the dramatic increase. Probably your best bang-for-buck route and something you can do with minimal risk and least hassle.
If you want to get much past those figures that's when it starts getting scary, not to mention expensive - 250bhp is doable on these but it's not for the faint of heart. That requires a turbo-swap to something bigger such as a BNR's GTX250, depending on exact configuration you're looking at between £1200 - £2500 for the parts and then labour to do the swap. But that's not all, a bigger turbo is pushing much more air at the engine and if you want to reach those power numbers (and for the engine to last more than about 5 minutes) you're going to need to increase fuel flow to compensate, the standard injectors can't keep up with the amount of fuel needed so you're going to have to swap the injectors out for something beefier too, which will cost you another £200 - £300 in parts plus labour. You're also going to need to get the car's ECU re-mapped in order to run the bigger turbo and injectors.
Of course once you've got your car pushing 100bhp + over stock you're potentially going to be going a fair bit faster than you were previously so that's probably the time you need to start looking at whether the stock brakes and suspension are up to it.
By this point you're probably going to be much better off selling the stock car and buying something that comes with this level of performance to begin with. 250bhp+ cars are far from uncommon these days and are often available at pretty reasonable prices.
So it really does come back to what are your goals here? - if you like the car and just want it to be a bit faster without spending a fortune a simple remap is clearly a no-brainer. If you just want a car that performs better and a remap isn't enough then trading in for something that already has the performance you want is the sanity-saving route. On the other hand if money isn't really a limiting factor and the modding journey itself is the motivator then you can go to town - talk to tuning companies like BNR and ZZP who have already done the legwork in developing upgrades for your car and they'll be able to guide you in the best direction.

Really good synopsis. The list of changes just goes on and on, like upgrading the head gaskets, improving the suspension to handle the additional power and speed, etc. Mega money.

+1 Outstanding reality check.
